# How to bootstrap Jackrabbit from code

Tags: repository, jackrabbit

I am trying to run jackrabbit repository from the application. Is there any way to bootstrap jackrabbit to start the repository. I couldn't with any deployment models mentioned in jackrabbit manual as I need to take the repository location dynamically from database. Am looking for stating/shutting the repository from java code.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options there :

- obtain the connection parameters from your database and use JcrUtils to connect to the repository.
- start your repository which requires the configuration file (repository.xml) and the home directory of your repository. You have some example in [Silverpeas code](https://github.com/ehsavoie/Silverpeas-setup/blob/feature_82/src/main/java/org/silverpeas/migration/jcr/util/RepositoryManager.java).